# How to create multiple array of objects in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

can anyone help me how to add multiple "Addons" per create ?
With this code I can add only one addons ..
(Tested in postman) but can anyone suggest me how I can make it to add multiple addons ?

Model

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type:String
},
price:{
    type:Boolean
},
addons:[{
    addonsName:{
        type:String
    },
    price:{
        type:String
    }
}]
```

})

Controller :

```
const addItem = await Item.create({
    name:req.body.name,
    price: idOfGroup,
    addons:[{addonsName:req.body.addonsName, price: req.body.price}]
});
res.status(200).json({status:'Success',addItem})
```

I "fix" it doing

```
 const addItem = await Item.create(req.body);
```

And in postman I write

```
{
"name":"Test1",
 "addons" : [
    {
        "addonsName":"Test",
        "price":"100"
    },
    {
        "addonsName":"TestTest",
        "price":"200"
    }
 ]
```

}

But Is this the wrong way of using .Create() ?

Comment: Add `[]` around the `addons` where you create the item object?

Comment: @cbr I fix it :D But still cant post multiple records

Comment: So is your question about how to pass multipel addons in the HTTP request, or how to create an item with multiple addons? If the former, are you sending the data as JSON or as urlencoded or as formdata?

Comment: Just pass `req.body.stand` as the `addons`

Comment: @cbr I don`t understand , can you clarify ?

Comment: Try `Item.create({name: req.body.name, price: idOfGroup, addons: req.body.stand})` since you're passing the `addons` array under the key `stand` in the postman body.

Comment: @cbr THAT WAS SO SIMPLE ... THANK YOU SO MUCH !

Comment: Great! Let me add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your postman sample, you're passing the addons array under the key `addons`. So just pass that as the addons:

```
const addItem = await Item.create({
  name: req.body.name,
  price: idOfGroup,
  addons: req.body.addons,
});
res.status(200).json({ status: "Success", addItem });
```

You could additionally use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) to get rid of the `req.body.` repetition:

```
const { name, addons } = req.body;

const addItem = await Item.create({
  name,
  price: idOfGroup,
  addons,
});
res.status(200).json({ status: "Success", addItem });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make the addons as Array like below you can see

```
const itemSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

name: {
    type:String
},
price:{
    type:Boolean
},
addons:[]

)}
```

In controller:

```
const addItem = await Item.create({
    name:req.body.name,
    price: idOfGroup,
    addons:req.body.addons
});
res.status(200).json({status:'Success',addItem})
```

Postman request payload:

```
{
"name":"Test1",
 "addons" : [
    {
        "addonsName":"Test",
        "price":"100"
    },
    {
        "addonsName":"TestTest",
        "price":"200"
    }
 ]
}
```